# How to perform action when given syslog message arrives on UDP port

Tags: monitoring, syslog, freebsd

I need to perform given action when specific message (matching for example regexp) arrives at the UDP port (syslog format). How to do this (i.e. by using already avaible softwere as opposed to writing one by hand)?

Comment: Do you really want to do it as it arrives at the UDP port? Or can it wait until the message is written to a logfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at **rsyslog**. Its syntax is much more flexible and easy than syslogd. Also is much more powerful overall.

In any case, what you want in rsyslog would be like

```
if ( regex ) then action

& another_action # This line could be ignored if you want only one action
```

Answer (score 3):

Syslog-ng can do this with something like:

```
destination d_special { program("/usr/local/bin/script"); };
filter f_special { match("regex"); };
log { source (s_all); filter(f_special); destination(d_special); };
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this link to logwatch manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logwatch) will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net) to watch the specific pattern and use the [active response](http://www.ossec.net/main/manual/manual-active-responses/) functionality to do do your desired action.